# How do I fix routing errors from rails in production mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, http-status-code-404, production

If I try and access some random string in the URL of my rails app, such as `/asdfasdifjasdfkj` then I am seeing a rails error message

Routing Error

`No route matches "/asdfasdifjasdfkj" with {:method=>:get}`

Even though I am in production mode. Clearly I don't want any real users to see this, and would prefer a 404 page. Anyone know whats going wrong and how I fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get 404 you need to run server in production environment and
use external ip address rather than local/loopback ip address in the url.

You can also force controller to consider all your requests as local:

```
  def local_request?
    return false
  end
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I've been scratching my head for the last ten minutes ;)